# spring-boot not using application.properties in tests

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, flyway

I have a project with spring, hibernate and flyway to create the database schema. So I have

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: validate
```

in my application.properties file. This config works during normal run (after packaging the executable jar-file and running it from the terminal):

```
2014-10-06 10:06:17.863  INFO 7519 --- [           main] o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator         : HHH000229: Running schema validator
```

but is ignored when running tests via maven.

```
1804 [main] INFO  o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export 
1805 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - drop table test_entity if exists 
1806 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - drop sequence hibernate_sequence 
1807 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - create table test_entity (id bigint not null, name    varchar(255), primary key (id)) 
1807 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - create sequence hibernate_sequence 
1808 [main] INFO  o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - HHH000230: Schema export complete
```

The main difference with the official flyway-sample seems in the I don't use the spring-boot provided maven-parent.

The complete project is [here](https://github.com/isopov/flyway-spring-boot-test)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your test isn't using Spring Boot (it needs to use `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` instead of `@ContextConfiguration`, or declare the appropriate listeners).

Answer (score 5):

You should define the **ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer** to include the application.properties file in your integration test. Just change your annotation to:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = FlywaySpringBootTestApplication.class, initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
```

I've sent you a pull request with this small change.